# When creating modal with showCustomModal(), dynamically replace original body component with new component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-attribute, modal

I'm doing a custom version of the 'Add Products to Opportunity' standard component, and I'm trying to fit a two-stage process within a modal ('Select Products' and 'Create Line Items').

I thought I could do it by having a container component that creates the modal and content, with another method that dynamically updates the modal's body with a new component.

It looks roughly like this.

```
showModalInitially : function(...){
     //Creating modal as per component library instructions
     $A.createComponent(modalBodyComponent, attributes,
       function(content, status) {
           if (status === "SUCCESS") {

               component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                    header: modalHeaderName,
                    body: content,
                    showCloseButton: true
                }).then(function (overlay) {

                     //Get reference to modal/modal body somehow?
                     //component.set("v.modalRef", overlay);?
                });
           }
    });

}

updateModalBody : function(...){
    component.set("v.modalThatWasCreated.body", /*Create second 
    Component*/);
}
```

I've haven't been able to get anything like this working, so far. Has anyone been able to do this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do what you're asking, as you're asking it. You would probably want to build a custom modal instead. It's mostly copy-paste from the SLDS documentation.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right. Thanks for the help 